# Are Postgres constrains per table or db?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, psql

Can I have two tables with different constrains that are names the same - that is:

Table A with constraint C

Table B with constraint C

The constrains are different

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Also, why would you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any suitable reference in the documentation but it would seem that the uniqueness of the constraint name depends on the type of constraint.

`unique` and `primary key` constraint names must be unique and may not be reused in multiple tables, but `check` and `foreign key` constraint names can be used in multiple tables (although that might be a bad idea for obvious reasons).

I would guess that the reason is that `unique` and `primary key` constraints create indexes and therefore needs to be uniquely named.

Comment: Not only indexes, but also a unique constraint on pg_constraint (which doesn't have a usable natural key) 2) Oops I checked, and it doesn't appear to be unique ...

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find where is it mentionned in postgres documentation. Here's a confirmation that constraint name but be different in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE type_position(
   type_position INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_type_position PRIMARY KEY,
   description VARCHAR( 64 )
);

CREATE TABLE type_position2(
   type_position INTEGER CONSTRAINT pk_type_position PRIMARY KEY,
   description VARCHAR( 64 )
);
```

And I got the message

> ERROR:  relation "pk_type_position" already exists